# Angular's ng-blur on input field not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not seeing it.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LurjLvz7/5/) that I would have thought would throw an alert message when the input box loses focus, but it's not working and I don't know why.

I was expecting an alert message when the user performs the following steps:

1. click the input box
2. type something
3. click somewhere outside of the input box

but these steps do not show an alert message.

Surely, someone knows what I'm doing wrong...?

Here's the code (same as the fiddle):

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">  
    <form name="myForm">
      <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" size="30"
         name="myInput" ng-blur="validate(myForm)">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.validate = function(form) {
    alert('blur!');
  };
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but assuming you are doing validation you should take a look at `ngMessages`

Comment: I had the same problem, and managed to solve it by replacing `ng-blur="doSomething()"` by `(blur)="doSomething()"`. I'm new to Javascript/Angular so I'm not exactly sure what this means, but I guess that in the second form, I'm binding the function call directly to the blur event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be your version of angular.  Your fiddle is using `1.0.x`  I updated you to `1.4.x` and its working fine:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">  
  {{santity}}
    <form name="myForm">
      <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" size="30"
             name="myInput" ng-blur="validate(myForm)">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.santity = 'Hello';
 $scope.validate = function(form) {
  alert('blur!');
 };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/LurjLvz7/6/

Comment: Ha! Hot damn! Thank you @Nix!